# possible for adverb to modify adverb before it?

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases, adverb-placement

Adverbs can modify other adverbs that come after it: "He moves very quickly."

But is there an instance where an adverb, or adverbial phrase, comes *after* the adverb that it modifies, instead of before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an adverb of degree "enough".It can modify an adjective or another adverb and is usually placed after them.

> I know him well enough.

Comment: Clever. Is that an exceptional word or part of some pattern?

Comment: It is an exception, I believe .